# Get the parent text and child one separately and store them in dictionary

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Suppose I have this html,

```
<span class="name">
  <span class="age">21</span>
  Will Green
</span>
```

I want to extract the `name` and `age` text and store them into a dictionary.

So far I have been able to get the `age`, but getting the `name` only has been difficult.

This is what I tried so far.

```
with open('test.html', 'r') as file:
    contents = file.read()    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
    
    name = soup.find(class_="name").getText()
    age = soup.find("span", class_="age").getText()

    results = {}
    results['name'] = name
    results['age'] = age

    print(results)
```

The output is  `{'name': '\n21\n    Will Green\n  ', 'age': '21'}`

As you can see the the `name` is giving me some odd characters, spaces and also the text of child element as well.

How can I resolve this?

expected output `{'name': 'Will Green', 'age': '21'}`

Comment: Not sure how that can be duplicate, you might need to read again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact that structure is still the same you could use `stripped_strings` and `zip()` it with expected `keys`:

```
dict(zip(['age','name'],soup.select_one('span.name').stripped_strings))
```

---

An alterntive approach could be to select age first and then its `next_sibling`:

```
{
    'age': soup.select_one('span.age').text,
    'name':soup.select_one('span.age').next_sibling.get_text(strip=True)
}
```

###### Example

```
html='''
<span class="name">
  <span class="age">21</span>
  Will Green
</span>
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
dict(zip(['age','name'],soup.select_one('span.name').stripped_strings))
```

###### Output

```
{'age': '21', 'name': 'Will Green'}
```